# How to stop a regex capture in a string with no newlines yet still capture globally?

Tags: javascript, regex, mustache

I'm trying to extract mustache template keys from a long string with no newlines. I currently have:

`\{\{[^><](.+)\}\}`

Which keeps matching *all character past each key's closing `}}` until it it finds the last occurrence of `}}`

How do I get it to capture each key and move on globally?

Here's a regex101 link: http://regex101.com/r/fU0iI6/1

Thanks

Comment: In addition to the answers about making it non-greedy, you probably want to move the `(` in front of the `[^><]`, so that the first character inside the `{{ }}` is captured as well. `\{\{([^><].+?)\}\}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it non-greedy regex:

```
\{\{[^><](.+?)\}\}
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fU0iI6/2)

Comment: there are other keys as well. how to get all keys?

Comment: OK got it by adding `g` we can get globally all keys.

Comment: Yes that is true `g` or global flag does that.